# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type I'm using a nuget called RLNET

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, nuget, roguelike

Here is my code and it gives me this error and I don't understand the solutions people give on the internet

explanations
Ruutu is a class
and maa is an instance of it.
And Piirrä is an method of ruutu which should draw the char of maa onto the console

precise error is:

> Error  CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Ruutu'

```
Ruutu[,] ruudukko = new Ruutu[100,70];

for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
{
    for (int y = 1; y < 70; y++)
    {
        ruudukko[x, y] = maa;
    }
}

for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
{
    for (int y = 1; y < 70; y++)
    {                   
        ruudukko[x, y].Piirrä(_juurikonsoli, x, y); //"error line"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error + where (what line) the error is thrown.

Comment: Ok im just going to go and cry because i failed as a programmer and i will never be a tech billionaire. Well if i look it positively i can now become and fulltime hippie and find true peace and happiness.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following instead of "error line":

```
Ruutu ruutu = (Ruutu)ruudukko[x, y];
ruutu.Piirrä(_juurikonsoli, x, y);
```